# @click bound to each item within v-for loop executed many times when clicking

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have a `@click` bound to individual items within a `v-for` loop. In the resulting render, I should have one `@click` for each item, so clicking one item should trigger the function bound to the item once.

Yet it triggers it as many times as there are items. Why?

```
<ul>
  <li :key="option.value" v-for="option in options">
    <QuizCheckbox
      @click.native="handleClick(option.value)"
    >
      {{ option.value }}
    </QuizCheckbox>
  </li>
</ul>

...

methods: {
  handleClick(val) {
    console.log(val);
  },
```

EDIT:
If I replaced ... with a simple  element, then clicking that  doesn't trigger the problem. So it's the `<QuizCheckbox>` component who's the culprit. However, nothing in it seems to indicate what could cause the problem. Here's the content of `QuizCheckbox.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div :class="['quiz-checkbox', {'quiz-checkbox--checked': shouldBeChecked}]">
    <div :class="['form-checkbox']">
      <label class="form-checkbox__label">
        <slot/>
        <input
          :checked="shouldBeChecked"
          :value="value"
          @change="updateInput"
          class="form-checkbox__input"
          type="checkbox"
        />
        <span class="form-checkbox__checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  model: {
    prop: 'modelValue',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [Boolean, Array],
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shouldBeChecked() {
      if (this.modelValue instanceof Array) {
        return this.modelValue.includes(this.value);
      }
      return this.modelValue;
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (!this.$slots.default) {
      console.error('QuizCheckbox: requires label to be provided in the slot');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      const isChecked = event.target.checked;

      if (this.modelValue instanceof Array) {
        const newValue = [...this.modelValue];

        if (isChecked) {
          newValue.push(this.value);
        } else {
          newValue.splice(newValue.indexOf(this.value), 1);
        }

        this.$emit('change', newValue);
      } else {
        this.$emit('change', isChecked);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your :key can't be an object; using an object may cause referencing issues because the key needs to be a unique identifier. Code looks fine otherwise, so maybe try `<li v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">` or `option.id` if you have that available in your data.

Comment: Sorry I simplified my code for this question, in my real code it's not an object so it's not the cause of the issue. I'll edit the question now, thanks!

Comment: @drake035 I'm not sure if this is also because of your simplified version, but you should not use the index as key, otherwise it will cause issue if you remove an element or change the order in your array (for example, clicking on an element would trigger an other element's listener)

Comment: Sorry it's still due to simplification, I have now put the original form regarding this

Comment: Please try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (insert a runnable code snippet in your question). Your code you post now seems fine...

Answer (score 0):

The code you post seems fine. Although simplified here is the code you post running:

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'ul',
  data: {
    options: [
      {
        value: 'option1',
      },
      {
        value: 'option2',
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(val) {
      console.log(val);
    },
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li :key="option.value" v-for="option in options">
    <div
      @click="handleClick(option.value)"
    >
      {{ option.value }}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to track the issue down to the `QuizCheckbox` component, however I still don't see what is the problem inside this component. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit of the second click event triggered is the `QuizCheckbox` `label` element and its relations with its outmost `div`.

You actually have 2 click listeners. The one you assigned on the outmost `div` element and the second is on its `input` element assigned by JS. The latter is also triggered by click on `label` element.

You cannot click the outer `div` (what you expect to happen) separately of the inner `label` (if you click precisely on it). Your click on `label` produces the click event to bubble (see capturing and bubbling [phases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase) of JS events).

You could avoid the second trigger by using `v-on:click.stop` either on `label` or on `input` element.

Or you could manage the event within your `handleClick($event, option.value)` handler (see the `$event` passed as first argument) and decide how to respond based on e.g. `event.target`: this would be either `label` or the outer `div` element.